# Ember routing design. Desktop like routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, url-routing

So, I want to build an app that would have the same effect as a desktop, so I have a load of routes and I want them to open in windows "(modals)", I'm not even sure if this kind of design is possible with EmberJS, but the only way I can think of is to have the URL ending to look like

> app.com/#/skype/files/chrome

This ending up having the 3 windows open (skype, files & chrome)

I would love some suggestions on this kind of design.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Honestly there is a large problem here, and that's the router is more like a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) than a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).  You can't insert/remove arbitrary routes from the current path.  You always push/pop from the end.

IE If you were to switch from `app.com/#/skype/files/chrome` to `app.com/#/files/chrome` you'd really be popping the three routes then pushing the two new ones which would destroy all of your state, then create it new.

Comment: Yeah, I gathered it was literally impossible, I've decided that ember is probably not the best approach to this kind of application so I've moved to angular and scrap routes as they seem impossible with any framework, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly feasible with the routing scheme you are suggesting. With this design, I would suggest the following routing scheme:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('firstModal', { path: '/:modal' }, function() {
    this.resource('secondModal', { path: '/:modal' }, function() {
      this.resource('thirdModal', { path: '/:modal' }, function() {
      }) 
    })
  })
});
```

With the scheme, navigating to `modal1.index` would show only one modal, navigating to `modal1.modal2.index` would show two modals, and so on.

You can then define the templates for each modal content and based on [this Ember.Component](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/), display the corresponding modal. For example:

```
App.FirstModalRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return params.modal;
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    var modalName = this.modelFor('firstModal');
    this.send('openModal', modalName);
  }

  deactivate: function() {
    // Remove the modal on exit route
    this.send('closeModal');
  }
});
```

Comment: I did try it, I can see what you're getting at, but it only allows for one modal at a time

Comment: @connorspiracist Yes, the Ember.Component I referenced only allows one modal at a time. You need to make modifications for using multiple modal outlets: `{{outlet modal1}}, {{outlet modal2}}, ...`

Comment: I've been thinking, I've got it working with the multiple outlets, but it's kinda impossible for me to use... It would be nearly impossible to use linkTo dynamically

Comment: @connorspiracist can't see what you mean about `linkTo`. If its feasible to make a fiddle to illustrate the issue.