# multiple Independent routes in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, routes

I'm looking for a way to get multiple independent routes, managed by the url in Ember.js. The Goal is, to get a Page that shows Persondata and Personrelated data on the Same Page. Here is a Mockup I created for better understanding:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/carcorg1ox0qjgd/Mockup.png (not enough reputation to post images, sry!)

I imagine a Start-URL like:

"#/person/123/Persondetails/Audi/Vehicledetails"

The Idea is, that I can change from Persondetails to Adresses without affecting the Bottom Part of Vehicledetails. The new URL should look like:

"#/person/123/Adresses/Audi/Vehicledetails"

And vice versa, changing from Vehicledetails to Engine, but stay on the Adresses route for Persondetails. The new URL should look like:

"#/person/123/Adresses/Audi/Engine"

I've already found an interesting [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703792/multiple-dynamic-segments-in-ember-js) to start with, but it shows only level of the dynamic Part of Routes. I'm experimenting with the router for a few days now and feel kinda stuck. Is it even possible to acchieve what I want with Ember?

I'd be very grateful for every little hint you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the router doesn't support this type of architecture.

It's possible someday you could hack it in with `query-string` params, but you'll lose a lot of the built in functionality going this route.

[Ember routing design. Desktop like routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923767/ember-routing-design-desktop-like-routes/20929536#20929536)

Comment: Thank You! Do you recommend any alternative Framework?